# The difference between lshw and lspci commands

Tags: command-line, lspci

I think it's a little confused issue but what's the difference the **lshw** and **lspci** commands ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

lshw lists all computer hardware and lspci list devices connected to the computer.

From [Ubuntu manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/):

**lspci**  is  a  utility for displaying information about PCI buses in the
       system and devices connected to them.

**lshw**  is  a  small tool to extract detailed information on the hardware
       configuration of the machine. It can report exact memory configuration,
       firmware version, mainboard configuration, CPU version and speed, cache
       configuration, bus speed, etc. on DMI-capable x86 or IA-64 systems  and
       on some PowerPC machines (PowerMac G4 is known to work).

Answer (score 3):

To put it very simply:

```
$ lspci | wc
     17     206    1509
$ sudo lshw | wc
     439    1464   19370
```

The `lspci` command only lists devices that are connected via the PCI bus. The `lshw` and `lshw-gtk` (the same thing but with a GUI) on the other hand, provide exhaustive information about all hardware in your system. This will include the motherboard, CPU, hard disks etc. It also provides way more detailed information about these including serial numbers and models.